# Что за оператор "?:"

Tags: php

где описание этого оператора?Это ведь не тернарный оператор!

```
// A
    echo 'A' ?: 'B';

    // B
    echo '' ?: 'B';

    // B
    echo false ?: 'B';

    // B
    echo null ?: 'B'
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сокращенная версия оператора ?: в том виде, в котором вы его привыкли видеть:

> Начиная с версии PHP 5.3 также стало
> возможным не писать среднюю часть
> тернарного оператора. Выражение expr1
> ?: expr3 возвращает expr1 если expr1
> имеет значение TRUE, и expr3 в другом
> случае.

[пруф](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Спасибо.У меня 5,3 но ошибку выдает Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Comment: Увы, но у меня php версии 5.4. И в нем у меня работает эта конструкция.

Comment: Благодарен за тест..

Answer (score 2):

Это тернарный оператор и походу это демо условий, оно должно вывести ABBB